# My loop bash command doesn't work

Tags: bash, shell, unix, for-loop, filenames

I'm trying to run a command called bedtools shuffle on a file 5 times and save each run as with its counter after the filename (i.e. SHUFFLE1... SHUFFLE 5).

Here is my code but I keep getting the error message below:

```
for i in {1..5}; do bedtools shuffle -i '/PATH/wgEncodeBroadHistoneOsteoblH3k27acStdPk.broadPeak_use' -g '/PATH/chrom.sizes'> rm -f '/PATH/wgEncodeBroadHistoneOsteoblH3k27acStdPk.broadPeak_use_SHUFFLED${i}.bed'; done

-bash: rm: cannot overwrite existing file
-bash: rm: cannot overwrite existing file
-bash: rm: cannot overwrite existing file
-bash: rm: cannot overwrite existing file
-bash: rm: cannot overwrite existing file
```

Please advise!

Comment: can you try `set +o noclobber` before your loop and let me know if it works? and why do you use `> rm -f`?

Comment: You have a `> rm -f` in your command which redirects the output to a file named `rm` each time.  And looks like you have `noclobber` option set which is preventing from the file being overwritten.